# Is it possible to zoom to custom map center with Zoom Controls?

Tags: openlayers

The OpenLayers example [Advanced View Positioning](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html) shows how to create a “view inside a view”.

[image]

If you examine the example, it uses a padding passed to view.fit(), from which you can correctly zoom to any point you want.

Also, if you look at the screenshot, fit operations center the map at point B, but clicking on zoom buttons use point A.

Is there any way to specify that subview when creating the view so all operations (animate, zoom, fit, etc) would always use point B?

One added problem is that default interactions like Map Rotate (Alt+Shift+mouse) rotates around A, not B. So it would be really helpful to define that subview to affect all view operations automatically, let’s say when opening a side panel, for example.

Here's the code for example:
CSS:

```
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
  }
  .mapcontainer {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .map {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 600px;
  }
  div.ol-zoom {
    top: 178px;
    left: 158px;
  }
  div.ol-rotate {
    top: 178px;
    right: 58px;
  }
  .map div.ol-attribution {
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 50px;
  }
  .padding-top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 170px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .padding-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .padding-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 950px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .padding-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    top: 570px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 30px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .center {
    position: absolute;
    border: solid 1px black;
    top: 490px;
    left: 560px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mapcontainer">
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <div class="padding-top"></div>
  <div class="padding-left"></div>
  <div class="padding-right"></div>
  <div class="padding-bottom"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
<button id="zoomtoswitzerland">Zoom to Switzerland</button> (best fit).<br/>
<button id="zoomtolausanne">Zoom to Lausanne</button> (with min resolution),<br/>
<button id="centerlausanne">Center on Lausanne</button>
```

JS:

```
    var source = new VectorSource({
    url : 'data/geojson/switzerland.geojson',
    format : new GeoJSON()
});
var style = new Style({
    fill : new Fill({
        color : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
    }),
    stroke : new Stroke({
        color : '#319FD3',
        width : 1
    }),
    image : new CircleStyle({
        radius : 5,
        fill : new Fill({
            color : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)'
        }),
        stroke : new Stroke({
            color : '#319FD3',
            width : 1
        })
    })
});
var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source : source,
    style : style
});
var view = new View({
    center : [ 0, 0 ],
    zoom : 1
});
var map = new Map({
    layers : [ new TileLayer({
        source : new OSM()
    }), vectorLayer ],
    target : 'map',
    view : view
});

var zoomtoswitzerland = document.getElementById('zoomtoswitzerland');
zoomtoswitzerland.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var feature = source.getFeatures()[0];
    var polygon = feature.getGeometry();
    view.fit(polygon, {
        padding : [ 170, 50, 30, 150 ]
    });
}, false);

var zoomtolausanne = document.getElementById('zoomtolausanne');
zoomtolausanne.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var feature = source.getFeatures()[1];
    var point = feature.getGeometry();
    view.fit(point, {
        padding : [ 170, 50, 30, 150 ],
        minResolution : 50
    });
}, false);

var centerlausanne = document.getElementById('centerlausanne');
centerlausanne.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var feature = source.getFeatures()[1];
    var point = feature.getGeometry();
    var size = map.getSize();
    view.centerOn(point.getCoordinates(), size, [ 570, 500 ]);
}, false);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863550/openlayers-view-center-of-rotation

Comment: Were you successeful in applying @Mike s solution?

Comment: @TomazicM Yes, thanks for the idea. I've used absolute positioning for my map, and jquery to calculate correct negative top value, since the width/height of my elements isn't always the same.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post your solution as answer so others may benefit from it.